# JavaScript close already open div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have given each of my div containers a unique id and some javascript. So I can click to Show/Hide each recipe on the page i'm looking at, but I would like to close any already open div via JavaScript when a new one is opened. I've included some extracted code rather than pasting the entire document as it's huge, below is also the live url:

*update - the `<?=$counter_recipes;?>` is just producing a unique number. the $i++ method and all further up the page.

Live url - http://bit.ly/1hQuzRI

```
    <h3 class="box2-title"><?php echo $row_rsCatalogue['pageTitle']; ?></h3>
<a style="color:#000" class="show_hide<?=$counter_recipes;?>">Show/hide</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#box_to_show<?=$counter_recipes;?>").hide();
$(".show_hide<?=$counter_recipes;?>").show();

$('.show_hide<?=$counter_recipes;?>').on('click',function(){
$("#box_to_show<?=$counter_recipes;?>").slideToggle();
});

});
</script>
<div class="box2-content" id="box_to_show<?=$counter_recipes;?>">
    <p><?php echo $row_rsCatalogue['pageSubTitle']; ?></p>
    <?php
        if ($row_rsCatalogue['pageId']){
            $rsPriceMatrix = $db->select('pageOption',array('pageId'=>$db->mes($row_rsCatalogue['pageId'])),array('sort'=>'ASC','name'=>'ASC'));
            $ingredients = '';
            while ($row_rsPriceMatrix = $rsPriceMatrix->get_row_assoc()){ 
                $ingredients .= $row_rsPriceMatrix['name'].', ';
            }
            $ingredients = rtrim($ingredients,', ');
            echo '<p>'.$ingredients.'</p>';
        }

    ?>
```

I can paste more if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your code:

```
$('.show_hide<?=$counter_recipes;?>').on('click',function(){
    //Hide open divs!
    $("[id^=box_to_show]:visible").slideUp();

    //slide down
    $("#box_to_show<?=$counter_recipes;?>").slideToggle();
});
```

A much much easier way is to give a common class to your divs that open and close, then just call `$(".someClass:visible").slideUp();` at the beginning of the function.

Comment: Oh nice. Ok well i've applied this but the page initially opens with every div open. *update - oh they can't close now actually eithier.

Comment: Sounds like you made a syntax error somewhere, check the console.

Comment: I can close one to open another but right now it's forcing me to have 1 open at all times. Need to firstly get it to show none (it's showing all open on page load), then close one your looking at right now with the same button, rather than this 'having to have 1 open at all times'

Comment: Edited the answer back to `slideToggle`, as for showing none on page load, use CSS `display: none;`

Comment: Updated the site. And what class should this css be applied to? (Been getting a lot of help with my code so far btw so still unsure of alot.)

Comment: Ignore, got it. box2-content. ok trying to put this together and see how things go. thanks for the help.